# Are there wildcards for use with the switch expression/statement in Ceylon?

Tags: ceylon

The title is my question. Specifically, wildcards are important when matching against values in tuples.

In OCaml it is possible:

```
match x with 
   (3, _) -> 5 | 
   (_, 4) -> 7 | 
   (4, 5) -> 6;;
```

A 'switch' contruct, that allows matching against tuple values without wildcards is not useful. In Ceylon, I think the switch is broken ;-).

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not yet possible. You can match a tuple literal (`case ([1, 2])`), and you can use destructuring (`case ([Integer i, Integer j])`, which is just syntax sugar for `case (is [Integer, Integer]) { value [i, j] = x; … }`), but you can’t use literal values to match in a destructuring pattern.

Comment: Is it planned to implement the same functionality as in ocaml's pattern matching?

Comment: I’m not sure; I remember there were some discussions about it, but none of the currently open issues I could find seem to cover something like `case ([1, x])` or `case ([1, Integer x])`.

Comment: Right, we do plan to eventually allow stuff like `case ([1, x])`.